# adding padding messing up the progress bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have following css class to add `padding: 2px` to add those vertical lines in progress bar but its messing up the progress bar as you can see in image. I earlier had `margin-left: 2px` but then it wont apply the background color white in those small vertical lines.

```
.ProgressGroup--progress:not(:first-child){
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

[image]

How can i fix that?

Comment: Show us the html please, and if possible create a stack-snippet

Comment: Maybe you only want to add horizontal padding, like `padding:0 2px`? But yes, it would help if you create a [functional example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Thanks @showdev i tried that it fixes it but the gap in second line looks bit bigger than first one. any idea why?

Comment: It's difficult to tell without seeing your code. My guess is that the second and third elements both have padding, so the gap is doubled. The first element has no padding, so the gap there is not doubled. Can you add your HTML code?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using divs then you can get it by using following approach, use `margin` instead of `padding` to get space each of others.

Below i posted an example, hope it will help you.

```css
.bigbox {
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.innerbox {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0px 2px;
  min-height: 25px;
  background:tomato;
}
.innerbox:nth-child(1) {
  background:black;
}
.innerbox:nth-child(2) {
  background:red;
}
.innerbox:first-child, .innerbox:last-child {
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="bigbox">
  <div class="innerbox"></div>
  <div class="innerbox"></div>
  <div class="innerbox"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the padding is added to all the sides, thereby messing the progress bar. The "blue" & "green" sections differ in height compared to the "red" one. Thus, adding the padding only to left and right won't mess the progress bar and also have those vertical lines!

This may help!

```
.ProgressGroup--progress:not(:first-child){
  padding-left: 2px;
  padding-right: 2px;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  background-color: white;
}
```